# How to covert a string to date format ddmonyyyy

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a string containing date in it.

It looks like:

```
01JAN2020
02FEB2020
```

I use the following code to parse it to date format but didn't succeed:

```py
a= a.withColumn('dt_one', to_date(unix_timestamp(col('dt_one'), 'dLy').cast("timestamp")))
```

Do you know the right syntax to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```py
a= a.withColumn('dt_one', to_date(unix_timestamp(col('dt_one'), 'dMMMy').cast("timestamp")))
```